# Strange answer behavior with SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a simple table using a non auto inc INT as primary key.
When querying the table with condition e.g. WHERE id='2,5,6' (unintentionally!) it returns a result set!
Ok, it works, but why?

Comment: please show a) the table schema, b) the sample data c) the full query, d) what it returned, e) what you expected it to return. Then we can understand exactly what is happening. Thanks.

Comment: This is documented See the section starting 'The following examples illustrate conversion of strings to numbers for comparison operations:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 3):

`id` is an integer and you compare it with a string `'2,5,6'`. MySQL converts the string to a number in order to compare the two.

Well, `'2,5,6'` isn't a number and other DBMS would throw an error. But MySQL uses another approach: it converts character per character until the string is ended or the character is not numeric. So it sees the 2 then the comma. Depending on your settings the comma is the dicimal separater or not. So MySQL either converts to 2 or to 2.5.

Here is the documentation on implicit conversions in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html.

The algorithm on how to convert a string to a number is not explicitly described there, but they say for instance

> there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

They also point out in that document that implicit conversion is dangerous, because strings are not converted to `DECIMAL` (as I would have thought), but to the approximate datatype `DOUBLE`. So in MySQL we should **always avoid implicit conversion from string to number**.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you. That was my guess.
The point is that the input id comes from a web form, so it is always a string....
(I can split the string by ',' anyways...)
Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: Note:
The SQL language interface is text based, thus 
WHERE id = 12345
WHERE id = '12345'
should work the same way?!

Comment: `WHERE id = 12345` compares two numbers. `WHERE id = '12345'` compares a number with a string. This only makes sense, if the string contains a number as in your example. So the DBMS tries to convert the string to a number and then compares the two numbers.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the documentation on implicit conversions plus some elaboration.